# How to write random numbers to file?

Tags: linux, random

I need to create a file containg 20 random numbers.
I tried this :

```
 for i in {1..20}; do n=$RANDOM; echo "no $i    $n">random number;done
```

Effect:

Numbers are generated, but they are not in file. Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are truncating the file every time. Instead, use:

```
echo "no $i $n" >> random
                ^^
```

You can also use `shuf`:

```
shuf -i X-Y -n 20 > file
```

- `-i X-Y` defines the range.
- `-n Z` defines the amount of numbers you want.

#### Example

```
$ shuf -i 0-3600 -n 20
2964
2825
312
892
3490
628
3123
890
43
3020
2004
3367
578
1698
121
2645
85
1743
1709
67
```

Comment: shuf -i X-Y -n 20 > file work fine, but when I try to use                 echo "no $i $n" >> random    I get a file with first random number repeated 20 times. Any idea?

Comment: It is strange, as `$RANDOM` should get a new random number every time. Does this work to you? `for i in {1..20}; do echo $RANDOM; done`